# Publishing APPX built with Electron to Windows Store and Desktop Bridge program

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, electron-builder, desktop-bridge

I have an app built with Electron and packaged with Electron Builder (https://www.electron.build/) as APPX.
I went to https://partner.microsoft.com/, registered there, paid the fee, and created a submission.
As I tried to publish the app I received from Microsoft the certfication report with:

**Capabilities: 10 Capabilities**

***Notes To Developer***

*Your account has not been approved for the Desktop Bridge program. The Desktop Bridge program is intended to support existing Win32 developers and applications.
Tested Devices: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, Lenovo Ideapad 310T*

On the packager page https://www.electron.build/configuration/appx they recommend "Register you app for the desktop bridge" at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge.
But the link is dead. 
So the question is how to get though this warning? What shall I do?

Comment: I'm checking internally but I think these days you just submit your app ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-distribute))

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support replied: "Regarding Desktop Bridge Program, this will get resolved once all other issues with the app are corrected."